# Optaplanner VRP example, multiple vehicles required per stop in same time window

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

We are using a customized **VRP** tutorial example to optimize daily routes for service engineers who travel to customers in order to execute certain repair and installation tasks. We do have time windows and we optimize 1000+ tasks for multiple weeks into the future.

Our (simplified) domain model consists of:

- **Engineer** - the guy doing all the work
- **Task** - a single work assignmet at a certain location
- **DailyRoute** - an Engineer's route for given day, consists of a linked list of Tasks

---

As a **new requirement** we must now support **two engineers** working in **parallel** on the same task.

Our current plan is to implement this by creating **subtasks** for the second engineer and implement a rule that their arrival time must be identical to the main task. 
However, this is problematic since moving one of the interdependant tasks to a different time (e.g. a different DailyRoute) will mostly **violate** the above constraint.

So far, we have come up with the following ideas:

- Allow **single task** moves only to a DailyRoute on the **same day** as the other task's assigned route

  - can be done via a SelectionFilter
- Use **CompositeMoves** to move both of the parallel tasks at once to **different days**

  - Do we need a custom MoveIteratorFactory to select the connected tasks?
  - Or can this be done with a CartesianProductMoveSelector instead?
  - Can we use nearby selection for the second move to prefer the same day as the first move's newly assigned day (is move one already done at that time)?

Answer (score 0):

For two engineers working in parallel on the same task, see docs "design patterns" specifically "the delay till last pattern". There is no example, but our support services have helped implemented it a few times - it works.

For the multiple stops at the same location: I've seen users split such visits up into smaller pieces to allow optaplanner to choose which of those pieces to aggregate. It works but it's not perfect: the more fine-grained the pieces, the much bigger the search space - the more that adding a custom move that focusses on moving all pieces together might help (but I won't start out with it). Generally speaking: if the smallest vehicle has a capacity of 100, I 'd run some experiments with splitting up to half that capacity - and they try a quarter too, just to see what works best through benchmarking with optaplanner-benchmark.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, we are already using a wait-time if the engineer arrives before the start of his timewindow and have extended it to also consider parallel tasks that start later.

Comment: I have tried to combine moves using cartesianProductMoveSelector, however I seem to run into the same exception stated in this ticket https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1464. I assume this will happen with any composition of chained moves where a previous move affects a following move. Can this be avoided with a selectionFilter?

Comment: I have implemented a POC of that filter and it seems to work, code is pasted in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340681/optaplanner-throwing-illegalstateexception-on-compositemove-created-by-cartesian